# PowerShell: using -replace with brackets not working

Tags: powershell

In the script below, the line `$comparisonFile=Get-Item ... \E")` does not replace the `$_` file `Q:\Backup Comparison\E\Files\file[1].txt` because of the square brackets. How can I effectively replace the text in the file name?

```
get-childitem -file -recurse | ForEach-Object {

    #file is: Q:\Backup Comparison\E\Files\file[1].txt

    $comparisonFile=Get-Item ($_.FullName -replace 'Q:\\Backup Comparison\\E',"V:\Q Dup Check Needed\E")
    $comparisonFileSize=$comparisonFile.Length  
    $newPath=($_.FullName -replace 'Q:\\Backup Comparison\\E',"V:\Deleteable\Q Dup Check Needed\E")
    $createNewPath=Split-Path $newPath -Parent

    Write-Host $_.FullName # result is: Q:\Backup Comparison\E\Files\file[1].txt
    Write-Host $comparisonFile # result is null

    if ((Test-Path -LiteralPath $comparisonFile) && $_.Length -eq $comparisonFileSize) {
        $comparisonHash=(Get-FileHash -algorithm md5 $comparisonFile).Hash
        $sourceHash=((Get-FileHash -algorithm md5 $_).Hash)
        if ($sourceHash -eq $comparisonHash) {
            Write-Host $newPath
            mkdir $createNewPath
            mv  $comparisonFile $newPath
            Write-Host ""
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What line fails within PowerShell ISE? What comparison is actually being made. Your code doesn’t run for me so you’ll have to debug the code and explain what values are being compared for us

Comment: I just tried it without `Get-Item` and the `-replace` worked fine. It is the `Get-Item` that is problematic. With this newest discovery, I have a bit more troubleshooting to do before asking the community for help.

Comment: Stack Overflow would be a better community for the type of help it appears you need.  Keep in mind, Stack Overflow (nor Super User) is not a code debugging service.

Comment: Thanks @Ramhound. I will pay closer attention in the future to correctly post my questions.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was related to the square bracket. However, it was related to the `New-Item` and `mv`. I adjusted the lines as such by adding `LiteralPath`:

```
$comparisonFile=Get-Item -LiteralPath ($_.FullName -replace 'Q:\\Backup Comparison\\E',"V:\Q Dup Check Needed\E")


Move-Item -LiteralPath $comparisonFile $newPath
```